# Nextcloud app installation on Ubunty dustro - SNAP_NAME not found

Tags: 16.04, snap, nextcloud

Currently trying to manually install an app on Nextcloud on a Ubuntu distro. Getting a strange error which I don't know how to solve.

`App directory "/snap//current/htdocs/apps" not found!`

So apparently that folder is missing. However I do have a `snap/nextcloud/current/htdocs/apps` folder. Strange that this is not being found. When I look into the `config.php` I see the following:

`$snap_name = getenv('SNAP_NAME'); 
'path'=> '/snap/'.$snap_name.'/current/htdocs/apps`

I think the env var `SNAP_NAME` is missing. I cannot adjust this `config.php` file. Any clue how I can adjust the env vars for `snap`?

Comment: Where are you seeing that app directory error?

Comment: It seems, there are two forward slashes here: `App directory "/snap//current/htdocs/apps" not found!` after snap. What happens if you remove one slash from here: `'path'=> '/snap/'.$snap_name.'current/htdocs/apps`?

Comment: Well the issue is that the `//` is in a `config.php` whic I cannot edit. I was wondering whether `env vars` for snap can be set so it would have the correct directory.

Comment: I get this error when I run `sudo -u www-data php occ app:enable facerecognition`